# May jar-file with annotations be excluded from the classpath?

Tags: java, annotations, classloader

We have a large java-application. One of my coworkers are now using this application as a library for a rest-api on jboss. In that regard, we had to add a @JsonIgnore annotation to some methods in some classes. I have to have an import in the classes as following for this to work:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
```

This annotation is included in the jar file jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
Now the question is, do I have to include the jar-file for all our customers that use the program as a standalone-application? Or can it be omitted since it is just anntations? The easy answer to this question is that I have tried running my program as a standalone program with no jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar in the classpath, and it seems to work fine. But what I really want to know is if it will allways do this, regarless of the virtual machine that is running. If a Java-update makes the application fail, either because of the annotations on the methods, or the import that is missing, the result would be disastrous, as we have a lot of customers using this application. So how are import statements and annotations resolved by the classloader?

Comment: How can your classes use @JsonIgnore annotations without the jar? Annotations are named interfaces. You're test must be a red-herring... If you're using Maven the app is probably pulling in the dependency transitively.

Comment: My eclipse which is building the app has the jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar file in its classpath. The question is whether these files that are built must also have access to the jackson-jar-file when started by the customers that does not have it.

Comment: Are you using Maven? Running mvn dependency:tree will show you if the classes depend on the jar. If you have jackson annotations in the application classes they will need jackson to be available at runtime... [@SEE Runtime Classpath vs Compile-Time Classpath](http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=866)

Comment: No I am not using Maven. I have jackson annotations, but the standalone-application does not need/use them. And the funny thing is that it does seem to work ok without the jackson-jar-file, the getters are called ok without any errors. But I wonder if I can allways rely on it being the case.

Comment: Interesting. I've typically use jackson in 'web apps' where it's used for object marshalling. In that case we had to have the libs on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been 3 years, but I need this answer.

It should work find, according to JSR-175 and Oracle's bug database.  After much searching I came across this statement in a bug report for an old JRE:

> According to the JSR-175 spec lead, unknown annotations must be
>   ignored by getAnnotations.

Here is the link: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6322301

It appears that you can compile a class with annotations and if the annotations are not present at runtime, it will not create issues.